# How to redirect to a child route in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I want to redirect to a child route within a module when the module is initialized.

For example if the current path is `my-app/masterview` (which is the root path here in my router config) I want a redirect to `my-app/masterview/overview`.

I tried it like this, but it does not work. The path is still `my-app/masterview`.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```js
 const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MasterComponent,
    redirectTo: 'overview'
    children: [{
            path: 'overview',
            component: OverviewComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'details/:id',
            component: DetailsComponent
        }
    ]
}];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having both a component and a redirect makes no sense. Either you want to render something or redirect.

Comment: The MasterComponent with the empty path displays a list with 25% of the viewport width on the left. The OverviewComponent and DetailsComponent are child routes with 75% of the viewport width (within their own  router-outlet). By default the OverviewComponent should be displayed and then be replaced when navigating to the DetailsComponent. That should be possible, or not?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the exact same problem right now, the following solution solved my problem:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '', component: MasterComponent, children: [
        { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent },
        { path: 'details/:id', component: DetailsComponent }
    ] }
];
```

Comment: just one note - if you are doing this somewhere deep in a route structure (many router outlets down the way), you may need to apply this at each level

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
 const routes: Routes = [
    {  path: '', redirectTo: '/masterview', pathMatch:'full' },
    {
    path: 'masterview',
    component: MasterComponent,
    children: [
      { "", redirectTo: 'overview',  pathMatch:'full' },
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'details/:id',
        component: DetailsComponent
      }
    ]
}];
```

I created a sample for you on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-fcomkm?file=app/app-routing.module.ts). Here on the sample the `""` route is redirected to children: `/home/users`.

```js
const appRoutes:Routes=[
  { path:'', redirectTo: `/home/users`, pathMatch:'full'},
  { path:'home', component:HomeComponent, children: [
       { path: ``, component:HomeComponent},
       { path: `users`, component:UsersComponent},
    ]
  },
  {path:'**',redirectTo:'/not-found',pathMatch:'full'}
```

Comment: Nope, I get --> router.js:1253 Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route 'masterview': redirectTo and children cannot be used together

Comment: let me create a sample demo for you and update my answer. I'll let you know ins some minutes

Comment: I created a demo for you and updated my answer. check it out please and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I made a change. try it now